# perl script which received email using sasl authentication

Tags: perl, email

I have use a script for smtp purpose on  Centos OS as given below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Net::SMTP::Server;
use Net::SMTP::Server::Client;
use Data::Dumper;

our $host = $ARGV[0] || "MY_IP" ;

our $server = new Net::SMTP::Server($host) ||
croak("Unable to open SMTP server socket");

print "Waiting for incoming SMTP connections on ".($host eq "0.0.0.0" ? "all IP      addresses":$host)."\n";
$| = 1;
while(my $conn = $server->accept()) {
    print "Incoming mail ... from " . $conn->peerhost() ;
    my $client = new Net::SMTP::Server::Client($conn) ||
    croak("Unable to process incoming request");
    if (!$client->process) {
    print "\nfailed to receive complete e-mail message\n"; next; }
    print " received\n";
    print "From: $client->{FROM}\n";
    my $to = $client->{TO};
    my $toList = @{$to} ? join(",",@{$to}) : $to;
    print "To:   $toList\n";
    print "\n" ;
    print $client->{MSG};
}
```

Now I have send email using application which using below information.

```
SMTP Hostname: MY_IP
SMTP Username: root
SMTP Password: ****
SMTP Port: 25
Send a test email to:   mahboobkheri@gmail.com
```

And when I have clicked on send email then found that email is received on smtp and it show below output:

```
Waiting for incoming SMTP connections on MY_IP


Incoming mail ... from MY_IP received
From: <abc@xyz.com>
To:   <mahboobkheri@gmail.com>

To: mahboobkheri@gmail.com
Subject: Test Email System
Message-ID: <9f0c1a999390053b8e64665749a047a8@resolv.fastreturn.biz>
Return-Path: abc@xyz.com
Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2014 12:20:48 +0100
From: <abc@xyz.com>
Reply-To: abc@xyz.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; format=flowed; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Hi,This is a test of the emailing system. If you received this ok, then everything is working as it should.
```

But if I have use no existing username and password (Fake detail) then also application send email. So I have the need to configure sasl authentication. I have try and also search on Google but can't find useful. I have requested to please help me that how write script which accept email using sasl authentication.

Comment: So your question is simply how to use SASL authentication when sending email? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, Flimzy. You are right. My question is how to use SASL authentication when sending email using perl. I have tried using a script as define above which receive email. I have send email using an application. But this script accept all emails. But i want that it accept emails only those which have accurate username and password.  Thanks